# How to unify states from the macro to the detail

Tags: color, data-tables, wording, badge

I'm working on a product that manage workers certificates, and so we have a table with ALL certificates where you can find cards for each one

Each card has: Certificate name, Next due date (29 days before expiration date), number of people with that certificate, Status badge and a Kebab button to eliminate or export that certificate. (Lets call this Parent table)

Then if you click on any certificate you will officially enter into that certificate and see everyone who has it (Lets call this child table)

The problem: Parent and child should use the same "Status and color coding badge"

Current status in Parent table are: All expired, **"N" expired**, Up to date, unassigned

Current status in Child table are: Expired, **Next due**, Up to date

So as you can see the conflict is between "N" expired on the parent table and "next due" on the child table

Possible solution: Eliminate "All expired" status and use color red for "1 expire and all"

Photo reference (Translated to English):
[image: Parent table] [image: Child table]

Comment: I think you're making it very difficult, so you hit a IA wall. There are better ways to organize this information, but even choosing this way, you shouldn't care about the child colors. The "parent" view informs you there are X conditions for each certificate. The child table only shows the people and teh conditions, that color relationship means nothing. As a matter of fact, as you already found, it only creates confusion

Comment: The color is a problem because im communicating 2 states with the same color.... Regardless of that, i would love an idea or direction besides a plain comment

Comment: that's exactly the point: do NOT use color

Comment: @Devin yeah but that solves half the problem, we would still have next due & "N" expired fighting each other because they are not equivalent. One refers to the future and other to the present

Comment: OK, I'm not sure why you have that Next Due part. If it relates to teh certificate, then the information about users and their statuses shouldn't be there, or at least shoukdn't matter since they are 2 different things (for what I understand). I'm commenting because I don't have an asnwer for this since I don't fully get what you want to do, but for what I understand the answer is simple: Workers have certificates. Certificates can't have workers. So you need to think another way to present information (since 5000+ workers list isn't realistic), probably without cards

Comment: Yeah i think this issue needs so much context to be solved here and for privacy issues i can't share more .Next due is there to avoid having an employee that can't work or do any given task because of it, and yes 5000 workers is a valid scenario (this is for biiiig big companies) on the other hand there are not that many types of certificates and that's why we decided cards so the user have a visual break from other tables on the platform. Thanks for trying to help i know is hard without more info